# Apache Ignite Continuous Queries on AtomicLong

Tags: caching, ignite

Can continuous query in Apache Ignite watch updates over AtomicLong type?

Can I just treat AtomicLong as common key value pair in Ignite?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible for `IgniteAtomicLong`, but you can easily create your own atomic counter - create a cache, put a single entry with `Long` value and use `IgniteCache.invoke(..)` method to atomically update it. In this case you can subscribe for updates with continuous queries.